# 3D CAD Viewer to Embed in Web Page

Tags: .net, activex, cad

We currently are using an ActiveX control from Siemens called JT2G0 viewer to embed a 3D viewer inside a web page.

However, I would like to find other comparable products to research and I'm having a hard time finding 3D CAD viewers that can be embedded inside a web page.

Does anyone have experience with other 3D CAD viewers that can be embedded inside a web page?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing more research, I think my best bet is to use something like Adobe 3D PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The [sence.js](http://scenejs.org/) will be your choice, if you try to display 3D model via html5.

But also [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) works too. More powerful for mechanical model.

If you just wanna to display a cad file ( like dwg, dng ...) use Autodesk & Microstation's display toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Autdesk has a free web [toolkit](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=823771) that does pretty much what you are looking for.  I haven't actually used that myself but have used similar products of theirs and was very happy with the results.

Comment: Interesting tool. However, it doesn't appear robost enough to handle 3D solid models and allowing the user to pan/rotate the 3D model.

Answer (score 0):

The [unity game engine](http://unity3d.com/unity/) has a [web player](http://unity3d.com/webplayer/) which may be an alternative for you. Not specifically for CAD, but I am pretty sure one can utilize it for this purpose.